# Random color ramp issue

Tags: qgis, cartography, color, svg, color-ramp

I have one set of polygons and one set of points sharing a common attribute (value 0-503).

When applying style with new random color  ramp (Categorized) the first set of polygons is displayed correctly but when applying the same new random color ramp to the set of points colors are incorrect.

I tried to create an SVG colormap using "[i want hue](http://tools.medialab.sciences-po.fr/iwanthue/)", and [SV2ColoR plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SVG2ColoR/) and it worked quite well (except that QGIS seemed to have problem with a large number of colors in the xml so I restricted to 100 in the svg in the end) but still wrong colors for the set of points. It looks likes something totally different is picked to display point.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you include a couple of screenshots to show the differences? Also, how are you doing the points (categorised/graduated)? (I've edited your question to add links, these look like two useful resources)